# Can't remove partially-installed extension

Tags: mysql, php, apt, dpkg

I'm on an Ubuntu 11.10 server with PHP 5.4 installed from a PPA. I had the MySQL library installed (php5-mysql) but wanted to try out the native driver (php5-mysqlnd), so I ran `sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd`. It caused some errors with dpkg, so I tried to remove it:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove php5-mysqlnd
Removing php5-mysqlnd ...
dpkg: error processing php5-mysqlnd (--remove):
  subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libapache2-mod-php5 ...
  * Reloading web server config apache2
Errors were encountered while processing:
   php5-mysqlnd
```

When I first installed php5-mysqlnd, it uninstalled php5-mysql--and now I can't reinstall that, as it tries to remove php5-mysqlnd. Now I'm left without a way to connect to my MySQL server in PHP.

How can I fix this problem? I've tried forcefully removing php5-mysqlnd (as per [php5-mysqlnd on debian wheezy/sid?](https://serverfault.com/questions/383624/php5-mysqlnd-on-debian-wheezy-sid)), but that gives the same exact error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/php5-mysqlnd.prerm`

This allowed me to install php5-mysql again. Modified from [How to fix broken synaptic updates](https://superuser.com/questions/22110/how-to-fix-broken-synaptic-updates-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state/210764#210764)